# How to write to file using Kotlin Coroutines. Is it possible to create FIFO?

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, synchronization, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to create logging system in app. I am thinking about collecting logs and saving them in a file. My idea is to do it using kotlin coroutines. So I made this:

```
object LoggingModule {
    private val sdfTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US)

    fun saveLog(tag: String, event: String, t: Throwable?) {
        if (t == null) {
            Log.v(tag, event)
        } else {
            Log.e(tag, event, t)
        }

        val fileName = tag + ".txt"
        writeLogToFile(fileName, Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), event, t)
    }

    private fun writeLogToFile(fileName: String, time: Date, note: String, throwable: Throwable?) {
        val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "APP_NAME")
        if (createDirIfNotExist(directory)) {
            val fileLogsDirectory = File(directory, fileName)
            val logToSave = sdfTime.format(time) + " " + note

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                saveLogInFile(logToSave, directory, throwable)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun saveLogInFile(logToSave: String, directory: File, throwable: Throwable?) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val pw = PrintWriter(FileWriter(directory, true))
                pw.println(logToSave)
                throwable?.printStackTrace(pw)
                pw.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e("LogSystem", "Error writing to the log file", e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to ask you for help in understanding what Im doing wrong. I thought when I use suspending method it will be blocked and then will be executed in correct order. Is it a good idea to use Coroutines  for saving to file when I need synchronized order?

Example of use:

```
LoggingModule.saveLog("ACCOUNT", "user logged successful")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspend function calls execute in order when called within the same coroutine. Your `writeLogToFile` function creates a new coroutine each time it's called, so there is no coordination between calls of `saveLogInFile`.

This can be done using an actor coroutine Channel, which allows you to send messages to it to handle in an orderly way. Actors are planned to be deprecated or removed in the future so there will be a compiler warning about using an "obsolete API". However, the replacement for actors is not coming any time soon.

First make a wrapper class for the data you want to post:

```
data class LogMessage(val logToSave: String, val directory: File, val throwable: Throwable?)
```

Also, create a CoroutineScope for your whole object to use, rather than repeatedly creating new ones.

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
```

Then create an Actor that will process the messages one at a time, suspending while the suspend function `saveLogInFile` is called or while waiting for another message.

```
private val logMessageActor = scope.actor<LogMessage> {
    for (msg in channel)
        saveLogInFile(msg.logToSave, msg.directory, msg.throwable)
}
```

Then modify your `writeLogToFile` function to send messages to the actor instead of calling `saveLogInFile` directly.

```
private fun writeLogToFile(fileName: String, time: Date, note: String, throwable: Throwable?) {
    scope.launch {
        val directory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "APP_NAME")
        if (createDirIfNotExist(directory)) {
            val fileLogsDirectory = File(directory, fileName)
            val logToSave = sdfTime.format(time) + " " + note
            logMessageActor.send(LogMessage(logToSave, directory, throwable))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's how I think you could do it without `actor()`:

```
private val logMessageChannel = Channel<LogMessage>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED).also {
    scope.launch {
        for (msg in channel)
            saveLogInFile(msg.logToSave, msg.directory, msg.throwable)
    }
}
```

And then send to this channel instead of the actor.

Comment: Coroutine actor is deprecated, any idea how to modify your code using up-to-date API?

Comment: @MuhammadSarimMehdi, Actor is not deprecated. It is marked "ObsoleteCoroutineApi", which doesn't mean it's deprecated, but rather that they plan to change how it works someday in the future so they want you to be aware that you might someday have to change your code. They've been planning this for almost six years but still haven't announced that they have started working on it, so Actors will remain for a long time still. But I updated my answer with a possible alternative. I haven't tested it myself, though.